# Equivalence class of matrices on linear form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We well know that if $M$ is a matrix on a field $k$ then the *equivalence class* of $M$ is uniquely determined by its rank (where $A \sim B$ if $\exists P,Q $  invertibles such that $PAQ^{-1}=B$).

This is like saying that morphisms are identified by rank, modulo isomorphism. I'd like to know how we can classify the relations between different morphisms (modulo isomorphisms of the space). This problem is equivalent to ask:

How we can classify the equivalence class of a matrix  $M$  where the entries are linear form on $k$ ( $k[x_0,...,x_n]_1$) but the matrices $P,Q$ have entries on $k$?

In symbols:

$A,B\in \mathcal{M}_n(k[x_0,...,x_n]_1)$ are equivalent if there exist $P,Q\in \mathcal{M}_n(k)$ invertible such that $A=PBQ^{-1}$

Thanks

Comment: I would think Smith Normal Form covers this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form  It just says the ring containing the matrix entries needs to be a PID. A book for this is Integral Matrices by Newman; I should try to buy a copy myself

Comment: Tanks Will Jagy, I didn't know it and it has been usefull. However, I've not well expressed my question, so I correct it

Comment: Also I need a generalisation for $K[x_0,...,x_n]$ which is not a PID in general